How to synchronize threads in WGSL compute shader that access storage?
I have this variable:
@group(0)
@binding(0)
var<storage, read_write> data: array<u32>;

And a function that modifies the data:
@compute
@workgroup_size(1)
fn main(
    @builtin(global_invocation_id) global_id: vec3<u32>,
) {
    // compute rotation and direction matrix and vector (omitted)
    let ray = ray::Ray(origin, rotation * direction);

    // function checks which node in the data gets hit by the ray
    // and returns the position and memory offset of the node within the data
    let chunk_hit = chunks::hit(ray, camera.position, 10u);
    let offset = vec3<i32>(global_id) - vec3<i32>(9);
    if chunk_hit.hit {
        var pos = chunk_hit.node_position;
        let size = chunk_hit.node_size;
        // same as `chunks::hit` but instead of ray intersection only point intersection
        let p = chunks::point(pos + vec3<f32>(offset) * size, 10u);
        if p.hit {
            chunks::remove_node(p.mem_offset);
        }
    }
}

In the chunks module this function deals with removing the node:
fn remove_node(mem_offset: u32) {
    var parent = data[mem_offset + 1u];
    let octant = (data[mem_offset] >> 1u) & 7u;
    // unmark from parent childmask
    data[parent] &= ~(1u << 4u + octant);

    // if parent index == 0u the node is the root node
    while parent != 0u {
        let parent_child_mask = (data[parent] >> 4u) & 0xFFu;
        // recursively remove parents if it does not contain any child
        if parent_child_mask == 0u {
            let octant = (data[parent] >> 1u) & 7u;
            parent = data[parent + 1u];
            data[parent] &= ~(1u << 4u + octant);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

If i only dispatch 1 workgroup per compute pass and thus run the code without parallelization this works perfectly fine. But if I turn the workgroup count up to e.g: [20, 20, 20] this breaks apart a bit.
The code works too if i dispatch 1 workgroup but let nested for loops determine the position of the voxel that needs to be removed.
    let chunk_hit = chunks::hit(ray, camera.position, 10u);
    // let offset = vec3<i32>(global_id) - vec3<i32>(9);
    if chunk_hit.hit {
        var pos = chunk_hit.node_position;
        let size = chunk_hit.node_size;
        for (var x = -3; x < 3; x += 1) {
            for (var y = -3; y < 3; y += 1) {
                for (var z = -3; z < 3; z += 1) {
                    let offset = vec3<i32>(x, y, z);
                    let p = chunks::point(pos + vec3<f32>(offset) * size, 10u);
                    if p.hit {
                        chunks::remove_node(p.mem_offset);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

If i let the parallelized code execute on a flat wall the expected outcome would be that a 20x20x10 cube is carved out of the wall, but the wall looks something like this instead:

If I let the code run trough multiple frames the desired cube will be visible just by random chance, so the position of cubes that get correctly removed is random.
I think this happens because I modify the data on multiple threads on the same time and data races occur.
I already tried to insert storageBarrier() and workgroupBarrier() calls before and after the data modification in chunk::remove_node() but this does not seem to have any effect and I do not really understand the effects of these functions.
I also tried to use var<storage, read_write> data: array<atomic<u32>> and use the atomicLoad and atomicStore to modify the data.
I also tried separately to have a var<storage, read_write> sync: atomic<u32>, which I use like this:
fn load(index: u32) -> u32 {
    loop {
        if atomicLoad(&sync) == 0u {
            break;
        }
    }
    atomicStore(&sync, 1u);
    let d = atomicLoad(&data[index]);
    atomicStore(&sync, 0u);
    return d;
}

But all this does not work.
I think that these kind of synchronizations only work for threads that are inside workgroups, but I could not find any clear specification that definitely says this.
I only dispatch a single workgroup with a size bigger than 1 that already breaks everything, so not even in-workgroup-synchronization seems to work.
How can I achieve memory synchronization for this storage array?
Both for only one workgroup and maybe even across multiple workgroups.
